# How to use assets lib in react native with NX?

Tags: react-native, assets, lib, nrwl-nx

I have a react native app generated with nx.

I want to use an assets library from the app.

The goal is to have something like this:

```
import { image } from "@appname/shared/assets";

<Image source={image}/>
```

or:

```
<Image source={require('/assets/image.png')}/>
```

or even:

```
import image from '../assets/image.png';

<Image source={image}/>
```

None of theses solutions work, there is no crash but the image is not displaying.

Problem: There seems to be **no updated documentation for react native**, all nx tutorials are outdated and don't work anymore with new project structure.

- There is no "angular.json" where I can set the assets path.
- The "run-android" executor in project.json have no assets options.

There is one way I manage to make it work:

```
<Image source={require('./../../../../../apps/appname/src/assets/image.png')}/>
```

Which means I have to use relative path (from my lib where the current component is located) to the assets folder of my react app, which goes against nx principles.

My project structure is like this:

```
project/
├── apps/
| ├── appname
|   ├── src
|     ├── assets
|       ├── image.png <= the image that can be shown
├── libs/
  ├─── components
  |   ├── src
  |     ├── lib
  |       ├── component.tsx <= component from which i want to display the image
  ├── shared
    ├── assets
      ├── image.png <= the image I want to use
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried with a library, with code like

```
<Image
      source={require('@appname/shared/assets/src/logo.png')}
    />
```

It seems fine to me. i should see the picture without any special configuration.

This is what I did:

1. create the assets library by running

   nx g @nrwl/react-native:lib assets --directory=shared
2. in the root tsconfig.base.json, under paths add

   "@appname/shared/assets/*": ["libs/shared/assets/*"]

Now in the app files, I could just use require to include the png images.

Comment: It does work if @appname/shared/assets/* target a folder within apps/appname/.
However, if it targets a folder within libs/ then no image is shown.
I've come to the conclusion that react native is preventing to show images from other directories and this is not a problem with NX.
In any case, thanks a lot for taking time to answer :)